# How to draw - dynamic - "safe areas" in ffplay

Tags: video, ffmpeg, draw, on-the-fly, ffplay

we need to preview videos with overlayed so-called "safe areas" according to this EBU document: [SAFE AREAS FOR 16:9 TELEVISION PRODUCTION](https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/r/r095.pdf).

Here's the scheme for 1080p resolution:
[1080p Safe Areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acMUH.png)

Those consist of three different "zones", each with the same percentage size-to-the-edge of the video frame for any resolution:

- **Action Safe Area** (GREEN box): 3.5%
- **Graphics Safe Area** (RED box): 5%
- **4:3 Safe Area** (GREY box): 16.25%

It should be easily achieveable using the *drawbox* command, but how can be dynamically adapted to any video resolution?